# Getting the multiple instances to show only the clicked instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, multiple-instances

Ok, this might be a simple solution but i have searched on stack overflow and Google but still not able find it out.I have `20-30` sets of boxes that you can search and click on, but when you click on them, everything else is going to hide, and then I will have a box appear with some information, if you click on that box or on next another box will appear and so on. And of course I don't want all the instances to show the boxes at the same time, I just want the once I've clicked on to show.

Right now I'm just focusing on the clicking of boxes.
Edit: I have now also made and js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tommhans/ymMW9/
The point is that i want the boxes text 1, then text2, ,4 to appear when i click a box.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $('.testimonial').click (function(){
        $(this).children().toggle(500);

      });

        $("#produkter").click(function(){
        $("#list").show(500);
        $("#list2").hide(500);
      });

          $("#omrader").click(function(){
        $("#list2").show(500);
        $("#list").hide(500);
      });

       $("#begge").click(function(){
        $("#list2").show(500);
        $("#list").show(500);
      });

    });



    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrap">

      <h1 id="header"><!--searchbar--></h1>

    <div id="buttons">
      <h3 id="produkter">Produkter</h3>
      <h3 id="omrader">Områder</h3>
      <h3 id="begge">Begge</h3>
    </div>  
        <!--Produkter -->
      <ul id="list">
      <h3>PRODUKTER</h3>
            <li class="testimonial">

            <a href="#/australia/"><img src="img/11034.jpg"><h2>CaterClean</h2></a>

            <div class="text">
            <p>Varenr: 11034 </p>
                <p>Bruksområder: Arbeidsområder, Åpne Flater, Kjøkkenbenk, Kjøkkenutstyr, Grill og ovner, Gulv.</p>
                 <p>Info: Brukes til deinfisering, la den virke i 5-10 minutter og den dreper omtrent alle bakteriene som er der. Kan brukes på de fleste områder. Er enten i 5lt kanne eller i 0,75lt spray.</p>
                   <div class="text2">TEST</div>
                    <div class="text3">TEST2</div>
                    <div class="text4">TEST3</div>   
             </div>  



                </li>


            <li class="testimonial">

            <a href="#/australia/"><img src="img/11001.jpg"><h2>Savona d2</h2></a>
                   <div class="text">
            <p>Varenr: 11001</p>
                <p>Bruksområder: Arbeidsområder, Åpne Flater, Kjøkkenbenk, Kjøkkenutstyr, Grill og ovner, Gulv.</p>
                 <p>Info: Brukes til deinfisering, la den virke i 5-10 minutter og den dreper omtrent alle bakteriene som er der. Kan brukes på de fleste områder. Er enten i 5lt kanne eller i 0,75lt spray.</p>
             </div>

                   <div class="text2">TEST</div>
                    <div class="text3">TEST2</div>
                    <div class="text4">TEST3</div>   
            </li>
```

Comment: Hey Tommy, i suggest you make a fiddle for SO users to play around with. This usually helps get an answer quicker.

Comment: [off-topic] There is an antipattern called 'magic number'. You should store 500 in a variable. [/off-topic] :)
[more-off-topic] There is a code principle called 'DRY'. Google for it. [/more-off-topic]

Comment: Hi, ok ill do that Mike :)

Comment: If you want JSFiddle to be happy you will need to self-close your `img` tags (i.e. with `/>'). Then the JSFiddle `tidyup` button can make things lovely :)

Comment: ok hehe, haven't made a jsfiddle before so first time for everything ^^

Answer (score 0):

From your description, this might be what you want

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".test").click(function(){
    $(this).toggle();
    $(".test").toggle();
        $("#info").toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: i'll test that out! :)

Answer (score -1):

edit : OP edited his question making this answer less relevant to his question.

I think you're attacking this from the wrong angle,

The way you bind events can be an issue, I suggest you create an object for each new 'box', the object can then have an array of all the different text items, from there you'll simply listen to clicks on an array item and show the next item in the array and hide the current one. (add logic check to see if it's the last item in the array).

Will make your code easier to understand aswell.

Comment: It should be a comment.

Comment: Well I think it's an answer, as it will both solve his current problem and probably future problems. but we can agree to disagree